# Navigationbar totally left

Tags: html, css

I have a navigation bar on my html website. It should be completly on the left side on the homepage. But with my CSS-Code:

```
    #mainnav ul li {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
    display:inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    float:left;
    margin-left:0px;
    padding:6px;
    list-style-type: none;
    width:22%;
    background-color: #093;
    text-transform: uppercase;
```

It doenst work. The Navigationbar ist a bit away from the left side. It's a beginner mistake, yes. But I dont have any idea and I have read a lot of html&css tutorials.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: can you post the relevant HTML? or a link to your site or recreate this issue in a fiddle? It's hard to tell what the issue is with what was posted

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS code is just applying to the list item of the menu, and not the root menu itself.

Change

```
 #mainnav ul li {
```

to

```
 #mainnav {
```

Also, if you are using the "id" attribute, what you have is correct, but if you are using the "class" attribute, make sure you use ".mainnav" instead of the "#".